# Custom login page in Java for GAE accounts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-account

I have a Java application, and GAE application. Here is what I want to do:

I want GAE account users to authorize in my Java application, and I don't want to use "Sign In with..." solution. Instead I want the users to login from my Java application login page ( e.g   providing username and password) and forward this login information to Google Servers.

In other words I want exactly this thing in this [page](https://login.unal.edu.co/sso/auth.htm). This webpage uses Google Accounts Service, but the login form, is a custom form that then (I imagine) forwards the data to Google Servers and then logs the user in.

How can I achieve that? What protocols should I use( OAuth, OpenID, GAE services... )?

Comment: So you are asking users to give you their password?

Comment: @PeterKnego - Maybe, because I don't know how it was implemented in the link above. As I am controlling the GAE application, anytime I can reset their passwords. I wont gain anything by learning their passwords.

Comment: Yes, the web site above sees your Google password - a big no-no. They can store your password and have access to your Google account any time they want, even impersonating you. I believe someone should make students aware that school is doing this.

Comment: @PeterKnego - So, do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: But, then - the email address is provided by school so this makes it "somewhat" ok (in part that they have access to your account, not impersonating you). But you should in no case ask for password to 3rd party services.

Comment: @PeterKnego - Only my GAE users will be able to login to my Java. So its ok to see their passwords

Comment: No, it's never ok to see passwords of services that do not belong to you, in this case Google Accounts. This is a big risk (for users) and liability (for you). If something goes wrong (like sending inappropriate/criminal content), than people can always say: hey this guy has our passwords, maybe he sent it. Just don't try to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a custom login page to Google Accounts. The whole purpose of Google-provided login page is that users trust the page when entering their password. Otherwise anybody could create a login page and start collecting users passwords.

If you need a managed/limited access to users account (with their consent), you should look into OAuth. But in any case this will not give you an option of making a custom login page.

Comment: - But how that University achieved that?

Comment: Technically this is easy to do: they created a custom form where users enter their email/pass, which is then sent to Google servers to authenticate. But this means they see users password which IMO is not ok. Technically they probably use the deprecated ClientLogin API: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Comment: Is it possible to implement custom login page for GAE app, and make a communication btw GAE and my Java app?

Comment: The university will probably have a SSO on top of Google Apps implemented, that is why they have a different login page linked to their own identity store https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224&topic=29818&ctx=topic